# Draw off center connection between rectangles

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am trying to create a [sequence diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) using draw.io

For that, I need to create long rectangles and draw multiple connections between them along the side of the rectangle.

However, using the blue arrow that creates connections, I can only draw connections to and from the center of the rectangle.  I have to manually drag the arrow to the desired position.

Is there a way to make this quicker?

Answer (score 0):

When you hover a shape e.g. rectangle, you will see blue crosses (there are more than one) which are basically connection points you could use to make connections to the other shape. One is central and the other two are top and bottom.

If you would like to add more connection points to shape, take a look at the following article:https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000042498-how-to-add-remove-connection-points-how-to-connect-anywhere-on-a-shape-